# Microsoft SSIS Package running successfully manually from Visual Studio and SSMS Integration Services Catalog, but not via SQL Server Agent

Tags: t-sql, ssis, ssms, jobs, sql-agent

I have a complex SSIS package, which detects the file extension from a folder, and loads the file into a SQL Server table. I have a For Each Loop Container to load a number of files in this manner, from this folder  location and load each file into a SQL Server table.

After the loading of each file into the SQL Server table, the SSIS has a File System Task in the Control Flow; this File System Task  first creates an archive folder and then moves each file into this archive folder.

I am using Environment Variables in the SSMS Integration Services Catalog, to map to the parameters in the SSIS package/project.

The entire process is successful when I run the SSIS package in the SSMS Integration Services Catalog manually, but when I try to run via a SQL Server Agent, the data loading and the (File System Task's) folder creation are successful, but not the File System Task's file moving process. (The Agent is Run as SQL Server Agent Service Account.)

I get the following error when I see the execution report in the Integration Services Catalog in the SSMS:

> File System Task - Move Files:Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Access to the path is denied.

While the SQL Server Agent is able to create a folder using a File System Task successfully, it is not able to
move the file into this new folder location.

Inside the SQL Server Agent History, I see this in the job step:

> Execute as user: NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT. Microsoft(R) SQL Server Execute Package Utility Version 14.0.2002. 14 for 64-bit.
>   ... Package execution on IS Server failed. Execution ID: 30449, Execution Status : 4.

I am not good with this permission issue in SQL Server Agent. I read about some proxy setting etc. but am not able to comprehend.

Is there a step-by-step solution you can provide me to fix this issue ?

Comment: I think problem should be at original folder, likely original folder you Agent account only have read permission, try to give full control for original folder.

Comment: I agree with BieBei - giving sufficient permission to the folder can resolve the issue. However if you are looking to create a proxy - go to Credentials under Security and create a  new credential using the account that can successfully runs the package. Add this to SQL server Agent - Proxies - SSIS Package Execution . Update you job to use this proxy by selecting its name in 'Run As'

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Agent job executes the package using the SQL Agent service account.  When you run the package manually, the package executes using the credentials you used to sign in.  Most likely the SQL Agent service account does not have enough access to the directory, especially if it has just been created.  Make sure the service account has "Full Control" of the directory the package is referencing.  To test whether it is an access issue, log on to the server using the service account credentials and manually run the package from the SSIS catalog.  If it fails for the same reason, you know you need to look at file system access for the service account.

Comment: Fixed by creating proxy

Comment: @user3812887 any info how to fixed this issue?

Comment: I fixed this long time back; i used the network path instead of local machine C drive.                     \\network drive.....\,,\,,

Comment: @kucluk       see this link:   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/572c19d4-2d38-41a0-a308-a9b715ad0f7f/ssis-project-catalog-deployment-environment-variable-for-location-information-accessing-file?forum=sqlintegrationservices